# C# send data from form1 variable to a user control

Tags: c#, forms, variables, properties, user-controls

I'm very new to C# and programming in general really. I've found many answers to this query but none of them make sense or have worked.

I have a name from a database, which is assigned to a variable - when the form closes and the second form with a nav bar User Control loads, I need this variable to be assigned to a label in the nav bar User Control. 
In other words, I need to send a variable from a form to a User Control in a different form.

So far, the best thing I've tried is creating a public property in the User Control and then setting it in the form, I know I'm on the right tracks but I haven't done it quite right. Something to do with creating an instance but I don't understand how it works.

```
//User Control
public string nameOfUser {get; set;}

//Form1
 if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
 {
  object a = dt.Rows[0]["forename"];
  string forenameString = Convert.ToString(a);
  navBar.nameOfUser = forenameString;
  mainForm objfrmMain = new mainForm();
  this.Hide();

  objfrmMain.Show();
  }
  else
  {
   MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Login.");
  }
```

Error with trying to set the property:

[image: Error with trying to set the property (screenshot)]

Thanks!

Comment: Who opens the second form?

Comment: See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: The second form opens via an if statement, when the login button is pressed.

Comment: As the error message said: navBar is not an object reference, means nabBar = null in this moment.

Comment: I'm still pretty new to programming so I don't fully understand what that means.

Comment: One thing you could do is make a public property that exposes `navBar` from `mainForm` and then use that instance (through `objfrmMain`) to set it's  properties.

Comment: I'll give it a try (once I figure out how to), thanks!

Comment: Slightly off topic but class names should start with an uppercase letter ie. MainForm(), NavBar()

Comment: i'll bare that in mind for future use - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ads a private variable on main form, name username, then averload the new method

```
Private String userName;
Public mainform(string name){
    This.userName= name;
    navBar.nameOfUser= this.userName;
}
```

Then for use

```
mainForm objfrmMain = new mainForm(forenameString);
```

Comment: Based on the question, `navBar` is the name of the Type, so that would not be the instance name on `mainform`. But if it was, this is a fine way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare a static variable "forenameString " in your main class.
2. Save any value in that variable `forenameString`

   `forenameString =dt.Rows[0]["forename"].ToString();`
3. Use this variable when you want.

   `navBar.nameOfUser = forenameString;`

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I just created a separate class with a public variable - probably not efficient but it worked in the end. Thanks for the help.